# Adding external data to sql table

Tags: sql, python-3.x, sqlite

I'm trying to add data from outside, but when the code comes here, **I get an error**. How can I add data from outside?

All I want is for someone to add the data to the table.

```
def ogrencikaydi(self):
        print("*******ÖĞRENCİ KAYIT YERİ*******")
        isim=input("İSİM:")
        soyisim=input("SOYİSİM:")
        numara=input("NUMARA:")
        cinsiyet=input("CİNSİYET:")
    
        baglanti = sqlite3.connect("universite.db")
        imlec = baglanti.cursor()
  
        imlec.execute("INSERT INTO HACETTEPE VALUES(isim,soyisim,numara,cinsiyet)") #non-working part
        baglanti.commit()
        baglanti.close()
        self.menu()
```

Comment: Why is post tagged `php` and `d` if only `python` code is shown? And please [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) before asking since many insert data questions with Python-SQLite/DB have been asked and answered.

Answer (score 0):

The query has a structure issue. is missing the data to be inserted.

One query has to follow the format:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);
```

Your query has the format:

```
INSERT INTO table_name                # columns declaration is missing
VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);
```

The query format that you used is valid if you are populating all the fields of the table with that query. Probably the error occours because you are not doing that.
Refer to this [article](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp).

Over this, you are not use the variables values, but the variables names.
This is because you are not using string formatting.
For that, refer to this [article](https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/).

So the solution is:

```
query = "INSERT INTO HACETTEPE (isim,soyisim,numara,cinsiyet) VALUES(?,?,?,?)" 
imlec.execute(query, [isim,soyisim,numara,cinsiyet])
```

I did update to a more secure version thanks to [@Parfait](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1422451/parfait)

Comment: **Warning**: the solution is open to SQL injection especially with user input. Use [parameterization](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/sqlite3.html) instead which is supported with `sqlite3`.

Comment: Modified as per your comment, I did not know that. Thank you